# C# Parametrized Method Array or Parametrized Method List

Tags: c#, methods

i want to declare a parametrized method array or method list. This means that there will be a method array and i can call the method by using array's index and at the same time i want to give a parameter to the method. How can i do that?

Comment: You should mock up pseudo-code to show what you're trying to do even if it won't compile. Also show how you'd call such a method.

Comment: Use delegates or switch-case. As Yuck said, its difficult to say  without knowing what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Do all the methods have the same signature - i.e. parameters and return value?

Comment: void (*func_ptr[3]) = {fun1, fun2, fun3};

Like that but i want to pass a parameter to methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the method signature, you can do something like this:

Using an example of a method that takes in an `int` and returns a `string`:

```
var functionList = new List<Func<int, string>>();

functionlist.Add(SomeMethod)


functionlist[0](12345); //call the function


//Assuming you had this:
public string SomeMethod(int val) { ...
```

Comment: What is "var" here? Compiler does not compile line 1 of your code. I suppose you have to declare global?

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? var is new, as of .Net 3.0

Try:

List<Func<int, string>> functionList = new List<Func<int, string>>();

Comment: Can i show methods on the line that i declare function list? Like:  List<Func<int, string>> functionList = new List<Func<int, string>>() = {m1, m2, m3, ...}

Comment: Sorry - not sure I understand your last question..?